# How to plot Time Series using matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I want to visualize these data:
Data Source : http://pastebin.com/vx9xLtdm

I couldn't group data per days.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
```

I tried the both

```
x = df.groupby(lambda x: x.created_date()))
x = df.set_index('date')
```

For visualization

```
df.hist(color='k', alpha=0.5, bins=50)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example based on your data using the hist method of a pandas.Series
(note that your data is a series and `squeeze=True` in `read_csv` returns a Series
in this case):

```
In [16]: s = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vx9xLtdm',
   ....:                 parse_dates=True, index_col=0, squeeze=True,
   ....:                 na_values=-9999)

In [17]: bins = np.linspace(s.min(), s.max(), num=50)

In [18]: axes = s.hist(by=s.index.date, bins=bins, sharex=True, sharey=True)

In [19]: plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

In [20]: plt.draw()
```

[image: hist_example]