# Python 2.7 time series non numeric values

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, time-series

I am using Python 2.7 and need to draw a time series using matplotlib library. My `y` axis data is numeric and everything is ok with it.

The problem is my `x` axis data which is not numeric, and matplotlib does not cooperate in this case. It does not draw me a time series even though it is not supposed to affect the correctness of the plot, because the `x` axis data is arranged by a given order anyway and it's order does not affect anything logically.

For example let's say the `x` data is `["i","like","python"]` and the `y` axis data is `[1,2,3]`.

I did not add my code because I've found that the code is ok, it works if I change the data to all numeric data.

Please explain me how can I use matplotlib to draw the time series, without making me to convert the `x` values to numeric stuff.

I've based my matplotlib code on following answers: [How to plot Time Series using matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277576/how-to-plot-time-series-using-matplotlib-python), [Time Series Plot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548179/time-series-plot-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib requires someway of positioning those labels. See the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["i","like","python"] 
y = [1,2,3]

plt.plot(y,y)  # y,y because both are numeric (you could create an xt = [1,2,3]
plt.xticks(y,x) # same here, the second argument are the labels.
plt.show()
```

, that results in this:

[image]

Notice how I've put the labels there but had to somehow say where they are supposed to be.

I also think you should put a part of your code so that it's easier for other people to suggest upon.

Comment: when you write plt.plot(y,y) you did it because y was 1,2,3? in any other case you would not use it ?

Comment: I did it for convenience. you could use xt = [1,2,3] but the y was already there. You just need a way to say where those labels need to be.